# Why is there no delay on Handler?

Tags: java, android

I have created a handler for an alert that should activate for 4 seconds, stops for 4 seconds, and activates again. When i put it in the if statement, it doesn't work; the alert keeps playing, stops for less than a second and continues activating again without the delay. Wonder if anyone knows why is it happening and what should i do to correct it. Thank you.

```
private Handler handler2 = new Handler();
private Runnable startalert = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        alert2.start();
        handler2.postDelayed(this, 4000);
    }
};

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {




    if (location == null) {
            speedo.setText("-.- km/h");
        }
        else {
            currentSpeed = location.getSpeed() * 1.85f; //Knots to kmh conversion.
            speedo.setText(Math.round(currentSpeed) + " km/h");
        }
        if (currentSpeed <=4.99) {
            background.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            handler2.removeCallbacks(startalert);


        } else if(currentSpeed >=5.00 && currentSpeed <=9.99) {
            background.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            handler2.removeCallbacks(startalert);


        } else if(currentSpeed >=10.00) {
            background.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            startalert.run();

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'this', use runnable object.

```
private Runnable startalert = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        alert2.start();
        handler2.postDelayed(startalert, 4000);
    }
};
```

Another method:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //Do something after 100ms
        alert2.start(); 
        handler.postDelayed(this, 4000);
      }
    }, 4000);
```

Comment: i added the picture on your solution

Comment: added another solution. try that also.

Comment: Nop. you used handler2.postDelayed(this, 4000);, replace this with runnable object.